# AWS Lambda trigger from S3 object creation notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have created an AWS lambda trigger from S3 - create object notification. I have used prefix to restrict a particular folder for this request. However what I wish to do is, restrict the S3 object creation notification only on the first file created in a particular subfolder and not for every file created. I have also tried using the suffix "/" but it does not work as none of the creation requests creates only just a folder, there is always a file with it.

Is there a way of achieving this ?

Thanks.

Comment: So you have s3 notification rules for each folder? Or one generic rule for all possible folders?

Comment: 1. Create object notification is sent to SNS
 2. Lambda is subscribed to the SNS 
 3. When the first notification is received unsubscribe the lambda from SNS ( unsubscribe in the lambda code)

Comment: I have one generic rule to the one master folder, files arrive into different subfolders and trigger the lambda. I want to restrict the trigger to only the first arrival of each subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want to achieve but it is doable with a DynamoDB to record the first file to each subfolder. Subfolder name will be your primary key. In your Lambda function you then check if the subfolder name already exists. It it does, do nothing. It it does not, do whatever further processing you desire. Of course the lambda is always triggered with any object creation. I can't think of another way at the moment. Will update my answer when I have something better.